# Bi-level optimization into linear optimization

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

Can the following bilevel optimization problem be reformulated into an equivalent linear program?

$\begin{aligned} \min _{\lambda, a} & \lambda \\ \text {s.t. } & |w|-\lambda+a w \leq 0, \quad \forall w \in [c, d]\end{aligned}$

I tried to split $w$ into $w^{+}$ and $w^{-}$; however, the resulting linear program has linearly independent inequality constraints.

Any hints will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you interested on SDP?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but sorry, a linear reformulation is preferable :)

Comment: Maybe let c = -2, d = 1.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked out the details, but here are two hints.  First, you can linearize the constraint by noting that $|w|=\max(w,-w)$:
\begin{align}
w&\le\lambda-aw \\
-w&\le\lambda-aw
\end{align}
The other hint is to rewrite the semi-infinite linear programming problem explicitly as bilevel optimization and dualize the inner LP.